# Creating a table with two columns

Tags: postgresql, table

I created a database with PostgreSQL, but I am extremely unfamiliar with SQL and databases and am having some issues.

I want to create a table that contains two values:

- "ID" which is my primary key.
- And "original_URL" field which will contain URL's with a TEXT type.

So I made this statement, which I think *should* work

```
CREATE TABLE ID_URL(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   original_URL   TEXT    NOT NULL,
);
```

However, I've come to an embarrassing stopping point. I created the database via the command line, but I don't know where to put this create statement to create the database.

Where do I run the above code to make it create the table in my database?

Comment: You can connect to the database with `psql` or some graphical interface (eg pgAdmin)

Comment: is that what people normally do @ypercubeᵀᴹ? It seems a bit much for the scope of what I want to do

Comment: Why would that be "a bit much"? You just enter the command at the prompt and you have your table. If you don't like the command line (although you apparently are familiar with it as you created the the database using the command line) you can use one of the many GUI tools available: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does installing new software in order to create a new table with two columns doesn't seem completely unnecessary to you? I'd understand if it was something more complex. It should be relatively basic command, and it was, I just didn't know you could use the command prompt to run that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a connection to PostgreSQL it is always to a particular database. To access a different database, you must get a new connection.

Using `\c` in `psql` closes the old connection and acquires a new one, using the specified database and/or credentials. You get a whole new back-end process and everything.

So lets say the name of your database is *mydb*

Type this

```
\c mydb
```

And than

```
CREATE TABLE ID_URL( ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, original_URL TEXT NOT NULL);
```

(The surplus comma that would cause a syntax error was removed.)

Comment: yeah, I was already connected to my database. I just wasn't sure where to enter the command. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

try using pgAdmin III an intuitive graphical interface for postgresql

[pgAdmin page](https://www.pgadmin.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using pgAdmin III tools or login to db using `psql` from the command line.

```
CREATE TABLE ID_URL(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   original_URL   TEXT    NOT NULL,
);
```

This syntax is wrong, you use a ',' before ')'.  The correct syntax for creating tables is

```
CREATE TABLE ID_URL(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   original_URL   TEXT    NOT NULL
);
```